# What does the "Normalized CSS" button do in fiddle?

Tags: css

I have been looking at the following fiddle: [Example of rounded corners](http://jsfiddle.net/JWb4T/1/)

It does what I want BUT only when the "Normalised CSS" check box is clicked. If this is not clicked (and in my code) then I see **spaces between the cells**. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the checkbox adds an [css reset](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reset-Stylesheet). without this, there's some [cellspacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2) wich causes the space between cells.

EDIT:
to get this on your own (without using the normalized css), just add:

```
table{
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't see where the cellspacing is. All I know is I get this in my browser and when normalized is set. What I want to achieve is the view when normalized is not set :-(

Comment: the cellspacing is part of the browsers default styling. just add `border-spacing: 0`, like i said, and everything is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/JWb4T/36/

Answer (score 1):

Next is the Normalized CSS checkbox, selected by default. If
selected, the fiddle will be rendered with normalize.css which is removing most of the
browser styling of many HTML tags.

From here: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html?highlight=normalized

Comment: I guess what I need to understand is what the setting is that it is removing that causes space to be added.

Comment: As the other answers suggest I believe this is what does it table {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border-spacing:0;
}